# How do I initialise a global map of string to function pointer?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
void draw_rectangle() {
    display();
    glRecti(10, 10, curr_obj_to_draw<T>->get_length() + 10, curr_obj_to_draw<T>->get_breadth() + 10);
}

std::map<std::string, void (*)()> str_to_fp_mapping;

void initialise_map(){
    str_to_fp_mapping = {std::pair<std::string, void (*)()>("rectangle", &draw_rectangle)};
}
```

Error :

> No matching constructor for std::pair<std::string, void (*)()>

Strangely, I was able to initialize it properly when it was inside a class, but putting in the procedural manner has messed it up.

How do I initialize the map?

Comment: Try either `str_to_fp_mapping["rectangle"] = &draw_rectangle<type>;` or `str_to_fp_mapping.insert(std::make_pair("rectangle", &draw_rectangle<type>));` where `type` is the type you want to pass to the template, such as `int`, etc...

Comment: Remy cleaned it up before I could, but be careful with the pre tags. They don't work that well with C++ code.  Prefer to indent all of the code 4 spaces to have the C++ code formatting respected. Select the code and click the `{}` button or press CTRL+K.

Comment: @user4581301 a lot of users have been using `<pre>` today to format code, I wonder why...

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `std::function` instead?

Comment: @Remy No idea. I'm seeing as lot of that and amassed backticks over the past few weeks.

Comment: Assigning initializer_list like you did should work as long as you pass a type to template

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize it directly using the constructor:

```
#include <map>

void draw_rectangle() {
    // ...
}
void draw_circle() {
    // ...
}
void draw_mona_lisa() {
    // .....
}
// templated function
template<class T>
void draw_type() {
    //... 
}

std::map<std::string, void (*)()> str_to_fp_mapping {
    {"draw rectangle", draw_rectangle },
    {"draw circle", draw_circle },
    {"draw mona lisa", draw_mona_lisa },
    {"draw string", draw_type<std::string> } // Template example   
};
```

If you do this, then you never have to call an `initialize` function because it gets initialized before `main` is called. If you put:

```
std::map<std::string, void (*)()> str_to_fp_mapping{};
```

This also initializes it, but it initializes it as an empty map.

#### Avoiding double-initialization in more complex programs

If your program is separated into several statically linked cpp files, you want to avoid double-initializing global variables. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55191830/4967403) for an explanation of how to do that.

Comment: *it gets initialized before `main` is called.* is very important. It means you can actually crash your program before the program looks like it's started running if you do it wrong, so watch out! Also keep an eye out for the Static Initialization Order Fiasco.

Comment: I added a section addressing that